# Volley error while making post request

Tags: android, ssl, ssl-certificate, android-volley

i'm making post request to the server, and i'm getting this exception. Please help me
[image]

Here's my code for login
(i'm sending JSON)

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, loginLink, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "response\n" + response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "exception\n" + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }) 

  {
        @Override
        public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
            return loginData.getBytes();
        }

        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/json";
        }
    };
    /*return "application/json; charset=utf-8";*/
    queue.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: Can you show your code ?

Comment: are you using `http` or `https` ?

Comment: I'm using https

Comment: @Raj check edited question